# RingCaptcha SDK import into android studio shows two app icons

Tags: android

I have added ringcaptcha sdk using android studio in my app. But after adding ring captcha sdk app shows two icons(My app and Ringcaptcha Sample).
How can I remove second app icon?
I have added following maven repository(url 'http://ringcaptcha.github.io/ringcaptcha-android').
Also added dependencies (compile 'com.thrivecom:ringcaptcha:1.0.7@aar')

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Launcher icons are added for an app by specifying `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in the AndroidManifest.xml.

If you have `LAUNCHER` specified for two different activities then you will get two launcher icons.

Take a look in your AndroidManifest.xml for two activities that look like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

EDIT: As you only have one LAUNCHER activity specified in your AndroidManifest.xml, the second one must be specified in the RingCaptcha aar.

This second LAUNCHER activity will be being added to the AndroidManifest.xml that is generated during the manifest merge built up from all the dependencies your project has (You can find this file under the build folder in your app if you want to check its contents).

You can view the RingCaptcha aar manifest by looking in the build folder of your project in Android Studio. You should find it here:

```
.../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.thrivecom/ringcaptcha/1.0.7
```

Opening the AndroidManifest.xml in this folder confirms it is adding the second LAUNCHER activity.

There are two ways to get around this.

Solution 1:

The easiest and best way is to use the latest version of the ringcaptch aar, 1.0.8.

```
compile 'com.thrivecom:ringcaptcha:1.0.8@aar'
```

Version 1.0.8 seems to have removed the offending activity so it should fix your problem.

Solution 2:

If for whatever reason you can't use the latest version of ringcaptcha then you will need to learn more about manifest merging and how to control and override items during the manifest merge. For example it may be possible to remove the Activity in the aar library by adding the following to your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="com.thrivecom.ringcaptcha.sample.MainActivity" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added repository in my app. In my manifest only one laucher category specified for only one activity. How can I check repository's manifest file?

Comment: @ShrikantSalunkhe Added more information to the answer. If you use the latest version of RingCaptcha the problem should be fixed. Try: compile 'com.thrivecom:ringcaptcha:1.0.8@aar'